# Using .net, XmlReader "look ahead"?

Tags: .net, xml

I am modifying existing VB.NET code, which I would prefer to change as little as possible since it works.

It currently reads an XML structure similar to;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootNode>
    <ParentNode>
        <Item ID="A">value</Item>
        <Item ID="B">value</Item>
        <Item ID="C">value</Item>
        <ChildNode>
            <Item ID="CX">value</Item>
            <Item ID="CY">value</Item>
            <Item ID="CZ">value</Item>
            <Item ID="CN">value</Item>
        </ChildNode>
        <ChildNode>
            <Item ID="CX">value</Item>
            <Item ID="CY">value</Item>
            <Item ID="CZ">value</Item>
            <Item ID="CN">value</Item>
        </ChildNode>
    </ParentNode>
<RootNode>
```

The existing code uses XMLReader to loop through the data. Sometimes the data will contain hundreds of megabytes in a single file so loading the entire XML at once would be a problem. While my example only shows a few items, in reality there can be more than 100 items in each child node.

As the program processes the data, when it gets to a ChildNode it needs the ability to retrieve the value from <Item ID="CN"> to process all of the other items in that particular child node.

Not being an XML expert, I am at a loss. What I have read so far indicates XMLReader is a one way reader with no ability to go back.

EDIT:

Using pseudo code what the current code does is;

```
sub processChildNode
    While true
        Read XML
        If in ChildNode then
            doProcessChildNodeItem
        else
            exit while
    end while

    sub doProcessChildNodeItem
        do stuff with current item
    end sub
end sub
```

What I would like it do do is;

```
sub processChildNode
    tester = getChildNodeCNValue()
    While true
        Read XML
        If in ChildNode then
            doProcessChildNodeItem(tester)
        else
            exit while
        end if
    end while

    sub doProcessChildNodeItem(tester)
        do stuff with current item
        if tester = "myvalue" then
            Do other stuff with current item
        end if
    end sub
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep memory to a minimum, use XmlReader (like you're already doing).
Use a XmlDocument (or similar) to store your matches (ChildNode and the associated Item elements).  This will work if your matching results are not too big for a DOM based structure (~100k elements)

Here's C# code, shouldn't be too hard to convert to VB.

```
    try {
        string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("t.xml");
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(strFileName);

        // Create an XmlDocument just to hold the matches.
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml("<xml/>");

        while( xmlReader.Read()) {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
                switch (xmlReader.Name.ToString()) {
                    case "ChildNode":
                        XmlNode ndMatchingChildNode = xml.ReadNode(xmlReader);
                        xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ndMatchingChildNode);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Now loop the matching subset
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>");
        foreach (XmlElement ndMatch in xml.SelectNodes("//ChildNode/Item")) {
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + ndMatch.GetAttribute("ID") + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>" + ndMatch.InnerText + "</td>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
        }
        sb.Append("</table>");
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());

    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: What I believe you are suggesting is to build a separate XML structure by reading the XML, When done use the separate XML structure to do whatever I want. I suppose while building the separate XML structure I could extract the value(s) I need for subsequent processing the separate XML structure.

Comment: Yes exactly, use XmlReader to read through your very large file, and put the matching nodes in an XmlDocument DOM document that you can crawl with regular XPath.